# Re-utilizar método

Tags: node.js, postgresql, npm

Fiz uma consulta para pesquisar um usuário. Funcionou!

Mas tentei fazer outra consulta, ele deu essa mensagem

```
Error: Cannot use a pool after calling end on the pool
```

Porque toda vez que faço conexão, eu fecho depois, e parece que uma vez fechado ele não reabre mais.

Estou usando o nodejs 10 com [postgres](https://node-postgres.com/features/transactions)

Esse é meu método:

```
       return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
                const { pool, errorHandler } = deps
                const query = "SELECT * FROM public.usuario  WHERE cpf = $1"
                const queryData = [ cpf ]
                pool.connect()
                pool.query( query, queryData, (error, results) => {

                    if(error){
                        errorHandler(error, `Não foi possível encontrar usuário com cpf ${cpf}`, reject)
                        return false
                    }
                    if( results.rowCount > 0 ){
                        resolve({ usuario: results.rows })
                    }else{
                        resolve({msg: 'Usuário não encontrado'})
                    }

                })
                pool.end()
            })
```

Perceba que toda vez que tendo acessar, passo o método `connect()`, mas não está funcionando

E ainda tem essa mensagem:

```
Error: Called end on pool more than once
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver mudando o código para

```
return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
                const { pool, errorHandler } = deps
                pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
                    if( err ){
                        errorHandler(err, `Problema ao conectar ao banco`, reject)
                        return false
                    }
                    const query = "SELECT * FROM public.usuario  WHERE cpf = $1"
                    const queryData = [ cpf ]
                    client.query( query, queryData, (error, results) => {
                        done()
                        if(error){
                            errorHandler(error, `Problema ao encontrar usuário com cpf ${cpf}`, reject)
                            return false
                        }
                        if( results.rowCount > 0 ){
                            resolve({ usuario: results.rows[0], msg: '', status: true })
                        }else{
                            resolve({msg: 'Usuário não encontrado', status: false})
                        }
                    } )
                })
```

Segundo a documentação